# State the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and use it to differentiate,

Tags: calculus

State the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and use it to differentiate,

$$F(x) = \int_1^{x^3} \cos(t^4)dt_.$$

> Thoughts: The fundamental theorem of calculus states if a function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$

Comment: Put your formatting properly, its not clear what u want to say

Comment: How do you expect $\cos(t^4)$ to have an antiderivative?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: @SimpleArt It clearly has an antiderivative. There's not a nice formula for it, but you don't need one to solve this exercice.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, that is right.  I meant to ask about an elementary derivative.  That, I do not think it has.

Answer (score 0):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states: Let $f(x)$ is a continuous function on an open interval $I$, and $a \in I$. Then the following function is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ on $I$: $$A(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt_.$$

---

Since $\cos(t^4)$ is continuous everywhere, we can apply FTC. Let $$F(x) = \int_1^{x^3} \cos(t^4) dt \\
A(x) = \int_1^x \cos(t^4)dt_.$$

By FTC, $A'(x) = \cos(x^4)$. Now notice that $F(x) = A(x^3)$. Therefore:

\begin{align*}
F'(x) &= A'(x^3)(3x^2) \\
&= \cos((x^3)^4)(3x^2) \\
&= \cos(x^{12})(3x^2).
\end{align*}

Comment: What does the A represent ?

Comment: $A(x)$ is the function that the Fundamental Theorem tells us is an antiderivative of $\cos(x^4)$. That is, we know that $A'(x) = \cos(x^4)$. This helps us here because the thing you are trying to take the derivative of is very close to looking like $A(x)$. So in the end, we use $FTC + $Chain Rule in this problem.

Comment: The interpretation of what the outputs of $A(x)$ means is the signed area between $\cos(t^4)$ and the $x$-axis on the interval $[1,x]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let$f(t)=\cos(t^4),  g(x)=x^3, $

$F(X)=\int_0^X f(t)dt$  and $G(x)=F(g(x))$.

$f$ is continuous at $\mathbb R$, then $F$ is differentiable by FTC at $\mathbb R$ and

$\forall X\in \mathbb R\;\; \; F'(X)=f(X)$

$g$ is differentiable at $\mathbb R$ then $G$ is dfferentiable at $\mathbb R$ and

$$\forall x\in \mathbb R\;\; G'(x)=F'(g(x))g'(x)=3x^2\cos(x^{12}).$$